# Replace "This PC" with actual - full - filesystem path

Tags: windows-8, filesystems, path

When accessing my libraries via *This PC*, the *This PC* keeps staying in the address bar. This is very inconvenient to me. I need to know where I am. I realize it is under C:\Users\Name\, but I need the address to just be there (for easy copy-pasting of addresses, as well as being coordinated as to where I actually am.). I have tried folder options to no avail.

So my question is: how do I get full paths at **ALL** time?

Comment: You can enable this in the windows explorer settings and enable it exactly how you enable it in windows 7

Answer (score -1):

Control Panel > Folder options > View > check "Display the full path in the title bar"

In 7, this was only available in the classic theme. I don't have a windows 8 box to test.

Comment: I have tried that previously; as I stated - it did not work, and via the control panel; it also does not seem to work.

Comment: When you click in the address bar to highlight the text, does it change the address?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Even a restart did not resolve this problem. The checkbox is still checked.